# Accessing the private data members of a struct that is in a namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm trying to access the private data members of a struct from a friend class as shown below. All the code is in a single cpp file:

```
namespace Foo
{
    struct TestStruct
    {
        friend class Bar;

        private:

            int _testNum;
    };
}

class Bar
{
    public:

        Bar();

    private:

        Foo::TestStruct _testStructObj;
};

Bar::Bar()
{
    _testStructObj._testNum = 10; //Cannot modify _testNum because it is private
}
```

On compilation, I get an error saying that _testNum in the struct TestStruct is private hence inaccessible. After trying different things and searching the web I finally decided to remove the namespace and the code compiles. Why can't I access the private data members of the struct from a friend class when the struct is defined in a namespace?

Comment: Beware leading underscores on names; they're mostly reserved for the implementation to use — so you shouldn't use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When saying `friend class Bar;`, it's still inside the `Foo` namespace, but your class `Bar` is outside. Use the unary scope resolution operator to specify that `Bar` is in the global namespace instead of in `Foo`:

```
friend class ::Bar;
```

You'll also have to either forward declare or define `Bar` before `TestStruct`:

```
class Bar;

namespace Foo {
    ...
}

class Bar {
    ...
};
```

Comment: It works, thanks. I tried adding the forward declaration earlier but it seems I was just missing the scope resolution operator. Can you answer me this though? I'm still playing around with the code and I realize that if you remove the private access specifier in the struct, the forward declaration and the scope operator the code works. You said because Bar is outside the namespace it should not work but why does this work?

Comment: @DanielJG, The only reason it didn't work outside the namespace was because it was looking for a class inside the namespace to be a friend. The issue only arose because of the friend class declaration's necessity. With a public data member, the `friend class Bar;` might as well not be there at all, since it won't make a difference, and `Bar` will be able to access the public member regardless of whether it's a friend or not.

Comment: Oh I see now. I just removed the friend class declaration and saw that the friendship wasn't needed to access the struct's members in this case. Thanks again.